# How can I create a Micrometer gauge from an async value?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, micrometer

I have a reactive Spring Webflux application with Micrometer.
I want to create a "gauge" metric like:

```
Gauge gauge = Gauge
  .builder("gaugeName", list, List::size)
  .register(registry);
```

or a supplier version like:

```
Gauge gauge = Gauge
  .builder("gaugeName", () -> getValue())
  .register(registry);
```

However, I have an async source of the value, i.e. a method that returns a Mono.
How can I create a Micrometer gauge from an async value?

Comment: Basically you have to update your `list` object inside the source method, since you already registered it on the gauge. It would be useful to know what is your method `source` and the value that you want to update.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the list object was given only as an example to show the method signature.

Comment: well in order for us to help you you need to provide some code where the value is to be fetched and when. Otherwise as you can see you need to schedule an update. There are several ways to solve this, but your question is too wide.

Comment: Could you add details of what the async code is doing and why it is async? Moving the gauge (or a different meter) into that code could be a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

For now I have found only the following solution:

1. Register a gauge at a meter registry with the `gauge()` method which returns a `Number` sub-type

```
AtomicLong gauge = meterRegistry.gauge("name", new AtomicLong(0));
```

2. Now it is possible to update it manually with the `set()` method

```
gauge.set(value);
```

3. Create a scheduled task that will run a reactive chain and update the gauge based on a fixed interval:

```
@Scheduled
public void scheduleTask() {
    Mono.from(getValue()).subscribe(value -> gauge.set(value));
}
```

Steps 1-2 are taken from here: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_manually_incrementingdecrementing_a_gauge

Step 3 is taken from here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

The approach has significant disadvantages:

1. metric is updated eagerly and not on demand
2. metric does not show the actual value and always lags behind in time

I'd appreciate is someone suggests a better way to create a micrometer gauge based on an asynchronously computed value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scheduling an update for your gauge, you could consider listening in on the current caller.

For example if the current code that calls `getValue()` were to return a `Mono`, you could use `doFinally` before the subscribe to update the gauge based on values returned.

This means the gauge won't update if calls aren't happening though.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
Gauge gauge = Gauge
  .builder("gaugeName", statusAgent, (sa) -> sa.fetchCurrentStatus())
  .register(registry);
```

where statusAgent is a fully wired component to perform the required async routine.